# I'm falling out with you

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I looked up the dictionary for "fall out". It means to have a fight with someone and then stop being friendly and stop talking to that person.

Sometimes, people tell you that they are not talking to you. For example, you have a spat with your girlfriend, and then she tells you she is not talking to you for 4 days.

Children also say this when you upset them.

I want to know what is the expression that can be used for this situation?

Example:
Girlfriend to boyfriend: Why did you forget my gift? I am falling out with you for a week. Please don't beg.

I know that fall out doesn't work. I know she can say I'm not talking to you.

But is there an idiom or expression that can be used for that situation?

Comment: Do people really say that? If someone isn't going to talk to you, they just ignore you: otherwise they are talking to you.

Comment: It's one thing to be too upset to talk, quite another to say in advance that they won't speak for 4 (or however many) days. Mature adults don't impose **the silent treatment** to punish their romantic partner.

Comment: Well, my girlfriend is very controlling and manipulative and she sometimes does that! Is it possible for someone to say this? I'm giving you the silent treatment for 3 days? Or another example: If you forget to buy me a gift, I will give you the silent treatment for 3 days.

Comment: _Fall out with_ is not used in the first person. Much more common would be a nominalization: _I has a falling-out with him/We had a falling-out_. Transitively, _fall out with_ is normally used to describe other people's behavior; it invites the inference that one or more of the parties are unreasonable.

Comment: People do talk about the silent treatment like that, yes. I known this isn't a relationship advice forum, but I don't think you'll find a therapist or advice columnist anywhere who thinks it's a good idea to stay in a relationship with someone who is controlling or manipulative (let alone both). Get out now before things become more serious.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't know about US usage but sentences like "I've fallen out with her" are quite common in British English. The falling out doesn't have to be mutual, it's quite possible for someone to say "I've fallen out with my husband because he forgot my birthday. He's trying to get round me but it'll take more than a bunch or two of flowers!"

Comment: @JohnLawler have a look at Google Ngram viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+fell+out+with%2Chad+a+falling+out+with&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20fell%20out%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20falling%20out%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20fell%20out%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20falling%20out%20with%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

The idiom ***in the doghouse*** can apply in this situation:

> In trouble with someone due to one's misdeeds or blunders.
>   *I'll be **in the doghouse** if I come into work late again this week.*
>   *You've been **in the doghouse** with Maria ever since you forgot her birthday.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by FARLEX](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+doghouse)</sub>